# Solve $ \begin{matrix} -1-\frac{1}{kx_1}+\frac{1}{k(1-x_1-x_2)}=0\\ 3x_2^2-2-\frac{1}{kx_2}+\frac{1}{k(1-x_1-x_2)}=0\\ \end{matrix} $

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

Solve $$ \begin{matrix}
    -1-\frac{1}{kx_1}+\frac{1}{k(1-x_1-x_2)}=0\\
    3x_2^2-2-\frac{1}{kx_2}+\frac{1}{k(1-x_1-x_2)}=0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$
in terms of k.

I just got $$ \begin{matrix}
    x_1=\frac{x_2}{kx_2+1-3kx_2^3}\\
    x_2=1-x_1-\frac{x_1}{kx_1+1}\\
    \end{matrix}
$$
But I don't know how to go further and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: solving your second equation for $x_1$ we get
$$x_1=-3x_2^4k+3x_2^3k+3kx_2^2+2kx_2+2x_2-1$$
plugging this in your first equation you will get an equation only in $x_2$

Comment: but then I will get a polynomial with order 7 which seems unsolvable.

Comment: This is right, but if you have a concrete value for $k$ you can use a numerical method